# Why aren't my NSManagedObject persisted after a [moc save] PerformBlockAndWait?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, persistence, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Still working on my RSS Reader.

My data model roughly consists of the following `NSManagedObject` hierarchy:

```
Category <---->> Feed <---->> Post
```

My application uses the following:

- a "root" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I use this MOC to persist my changes to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.
- a "main" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I use this MOC to feed my GUI.
- "Local" `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` Concurrency type. I create and use this MOC each time I batch-fetch new Posts objects.

Once the `MainViewController` is loaded, it populates itself if empty.

At the end of the `populate`method, I make sure everything's properly persisted and also refetch my data:

```
[_mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *error;
    if (![_mainMOC save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"[MainViewController::populate] Error.mainMOC: %@\n%@", [error description], [error userInfo]);

    }
    [[_mainMOC parentContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error;
        if (![[_mainMOC parentContext] save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"[MainViewController::populate] Error.saveMOC: %@\n%@", [error description], [error userInfo]);

        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"[MainViewController::populate] OK.saveMOC");
}];
NSLog(@"[MainViewController::populate] OK.mainMOC");
[_mainMOC performBlock:^{
    NSError *error;
    if (![_mainMOC executeFetchRequest:[_fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"[MainViewController::populate] refetch: %@\n%@", [error description], [error userInfo]);

    }
}];
```

Despite this, I cannot create `Post`s within my `Feed`s in a dedicated `localMOC``:

```
NSManagedObjectID *feedID=[f objectID];
if ([feedID isTemporaryID]) {
    NSLog(@"Warning %@ has not yet been persisted!", f.name);
}
/* ... */
NSManagedObjectContext *localMOC;
localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[localMOC setParentContext:self.mainMOC];
/* ... */
[localMOC performBlock:^{
    NSError *error=nil;
    Feed *feed=((Feed *)[localMOC existingObjectWithID:feedID error:&error]);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[MAsterViewController::fetchPosts] %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        return;
    }
/* ... */
```

The above bit of code produces the following log:

```
2013-11-14 19:24:04.847 uRSS[10907:70b] Warning Maddox has not yet been persisted!
2013-11-14 19:24:04.847 uRSS[10907:1303] [MAsterViewController::fetchPosts] The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)
```

Could someone tell me what's going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problems by implementing my own save routine:

```
[_localMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
    NSError *errLoc=nil;

    if (![self.mainMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[[[_mainMOC insertedObjects]     arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[_mainMOC updatedObjects]]] error:&errLoc]) {
    NSLog(@" ... ");
    }

    if (![_localMOC save:&errLoc]) {
      NSLog(@" ... ");
    }
    [_mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *errMain=nil;
        if (![_mainMOC save:&errMain]) {
            NSLog(@" ... ");
        }
    }]
}];
```

Note that `_mainMOC` is being observed from the `AppDelegate` and will have its changes asynchronically persisted to disk by his `_saveMOC` parent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for one context to access another context "temporary" (unsaved) object without some kind of a save/change operation taking place.

a context is a scratchpad, owning alone its changes until it decide to share them by committing a save operation (you could also listen to context change notifications).

In your case:
The `main` context created an item (before the `local` context existed).
Then, you try to access this item from the `local` context, without persisting the object first (or obtaining a permanent ID).

In order to accomplish this kind of flow, you will need to at least obtain a permanent ID for you object: `[self.mainMOC obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[f] error:&error]`

**Note:**
Despite the `main` MOC being the parent of the `local` context, using the `existingObjectWithID:error:` method of the `local` context will only look for the object in the registered objects of the `local` context. otherwise, it will try to fetch from the store. obtaining a permanent ID will cause the `local` context to try and access the store (or parent context) in order to fetch the object.

Comment: Hello, *Thanks* a lot for your help. So I guess my multiple ``performBlockAndWait...save`` block doesn't have any effect?

Comment: Since the `local` context did not save, and was not able to change the object then no. but all changes made to the `main` context will be persisted.